# SQL select DISTINCT values from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I hope that I formulated tittle right.

I'm trying to make tag's for posts, like for example in instagram.

User can add up to 3 tags. I save them in each in separate database column. (tag1/tag2/tag3) and later want to display only distinct values and their count total. No matter in what column they are located.

For example I have 2 different mysql rows(posts)

row 1 have : tag1 = house, tag2 = kitchen, tag3 = null

row 2 have : tag1 = home, tag2 = garden, tag3 = house

And I want to display **house(2)**/kitchen(1)/garden(1)/home(1)

Result that I get : **house(1)**/kitchen(1)/garden(1)/home(1)/**house(1)** because each `house` are in different column.

I have database table (diy_posts):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJvy1.png)

My idea of sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.tag1 as tag1, p.tag2 as tag2, p.tag3 as tag3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.tag1=tag1 OR p.tag2=tag2 OR p.tag3=tag3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count FROM diy_posts p GROUP BY p.id
```

And displaying them like:

```
foreach ($diyTags as $tag) {
  echo $tag['tag1']; echo $tag['count'];
  echo $tag['tag2']; echo $tag['count'];
  echo $tag['tag3']; echo $tag['count'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by unpivoting the table:

```
select tag, count(*)
from ((select p.tag1 as tag from diy_posts p) union all
      (select p.tag2 as tag from diy_posts p) union all
      (select p.tag3 as tag from diy_posts p) 
     ) pt
group by tag;
```

The need to do this suggests that you may not have the right data model.  The more typical model would be:

```
create table postTags (
    postTagid int auto_increment primary key,
    postId int,
    tag_number int,
    tag varchar(255)
);
```

I do note that this will require a trigger to limit the number of tags to three -- if that is, indeed, desirable.  This also makes it possible for the database to prevent duplicate tags, simply by defining a unique constraint or index.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I will check it as answer when I can. If I understood your idea right. It dosn't work for me. Because idea is like in instagram. Every user can think of his own tag. So there might be thousand's of them.

Comment: @ArtisUļjanovs . .  That's not a problem.  In fact, it might be even better to store each tag on a separate row, so it is simpler to get the list of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your Desired Output is not possible with Distinct Keyword.

- Also for desired output your Table schema is wrong. it must be verticle instead of horizontal.
- Still in the existing Table structure you can get desired output by doing comparision and counting process in ServerSide (PHP seems in your case).

Thats the only way in my guess to achive ouput in existing schema.
- However that will ruin performance when tag and post size increase hence you need to change your table schema or you can approach for the child table too.

Comment: For better sql performance it's better to split all data into more child tables? Because I had like that before. Now I'm rewriting all my cms to less and more structured data tables.

Comment: Yes exactly you can see to the other solutions which people have suggested. They have to use UNION of output of all 3 Queryes Because to do agrregation which is very costly in performance point of view if there are large data. Hence its suggestable to utlilise the child tables.

Answer (score -1):

Turn it into a single column and do the sum:

```
select tag, count(*) as counts
from
(
SELECT p.tag1 as tag FROM diy_posts
UNION ALL
SELECT p.tag2 as tag FROM diy_posts
UNION ALL
SELECT p.tag3 as tag FROM diy_posts
) tmp
GROUP BY tag;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.